# Best way to determine the last/current/active member in a group

Tags: sql, mysql

At my company, we receive documents that may exist in multiple versions, and it is imperative for us to store all of these versions in our database.

Documents can be inserted in any order (e.g., we could receive version 2 after version 3) and this can happen concurrently. However, we cannot have multiple records with the same pair of (identifier, version).

Additionally, we need to retrieve the last/current/active version of a document. I can envision two ways to achieve this:

### (1) Adding an active column on the document

In this approach, we would need to add a `unique constraint (identifier, CASE WHEN active = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)` to ensure there is only one active document for a group of documents sharing the same identifier.

| pk | identifier | version | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | foo | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | bar | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | bar | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | foo | 2 | 0 |

Managing the active column could be the responsibility of either:

- The inserting application, which would have to determine if the to-be-inserted record is active and, if yes, deactivate the existing active record in the database.
- A trigger (after insert), which would essentially perform the same task.

### (2) Determining the last/current/active version in the retrieving query

For this solution, it could be achieved using a window function or a `NOT EXISTS` clause, for example:

- `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ..., CASE WHEN version = MAX(version) OVER (PARTITION BY identifier) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS active FROM Document) d WHERE d.active = 1`
- `SELECT ... FROM Document d WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Document x WHERE d.identifier = x.identifier AND x.version > d.version)`

The drawback I see with solution (1) is that if two documents with the same identifier but different versions are inserted simultaneously, both could be considered active, leading to a failure due to the unique constraint.
Handling this kind of problem in the inserting application might be challenging (I would prefer to find a solution that does not put the insertion in jeopardy).

Regarding solution (2), the concern is about performance and repetitiveness. It's essential to evaluate whether a window function or a clause which will be repeated in *each* query working with active documents, or views would be more efficient.

So basically, I have a hard time choosing between the 2.

I don't know if that kind of problem has a well-established name that I could google to find other/better solutions and/or trade-offs? Does this problem have a *universally* recommended solution?

To sum it up:

1. an active column is easy to use but more complicated to manage (and the unique constraint could lead to more failures)
2. determining the last/current/active in the query/view can be repetitive and less performant but would not cause any failure at insertion time

I am using MySQL 8.

*UPDATE*

Typical use-case: select all active documents for a specific customer (`select * from document where active = 1 and customer_id = 123` for solution 1. Solution 2 is a bit more problematic in this case).

Comment: Now that I think about it, solution (1) could use `select ... for update` to lock all records with the same identifier (or at least the current/active/last one) to prevent problems with the unique constraint. But that won't work if versions 1 and 2 are inserted simultaneously and no active record exists in DB for the same identifier.

Comment: You should add some useful information: first a tag for the DBMS you are using (which I understand is MySql) but also the queries you intend to do.  You have correctly described the insertion but the selection is important too, like: only select the last version of a specific document in 1 query? or select the last version of all documents at once? select the last N versions of 1 or several documents? etc.

Comment: Most selections would be to find out the active version of a specific document.

Comment: What database and version are you using? `GROUP BY` doesn't return members, it flattens all group rows to a single row. You can use [windowing functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) like `FIRST_VALUE(version) OVER (PARTITION BY identifier ORDER BY whatever` or `LAST_VALUE`

Comment: Then at first glance: solution 2 with `SELECT * FROM Document WHERE identifier = 'foo' ORDER BY version DESC LIMIT 1` to get only the 1 record of a document. Extremely easy for an index to manage. Makes sense?

Comment: Solution #2 hands down.

Comment: "...Regarding solution (2), the concern is about performance and repetitiveness..." -- That would depend on the specific queries you will run. Are you going to SELECT for a single document, all the documents of the database, other? Please include the specific queries you need to optimize.

Comment: I am using MySQL 8 and I may need to return multiple documents (but only the last version of them) in a single query (e.g., all documents for a specific customer)

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, but the answer is, "It depends."  Either solution will work fine depending on how you're using the table.

Solution 1 will work fine even with multiple inserts happening at the same time, since there is (in theory) a low level lock occurring on the table.  What you can do is have a stored procedure manage the insert and update of identifying the record that is to be "active" by using a "Begin Transaction and Commit Transaction" wrapper.  A subsequent read will not have a problem since it is "blocked" from pulling the record till a clean read can occur.   The problem with this is based on size of the table.  The larger the size of the table, few million records, you may have just large enough delays that you might run into a locking situation.  VERY unlikely, but still possible.

Solution 2 will work pretty well also on large or small data sizes.  You could optimize the check with indexes to help speed up the check, but then you have query speed checks as a concern.

Too bad you're on mysql8 because you could have used a indexed view and that might be the silliest but fastest way to solve your problem by creating a view that only pulls "active" records and then indexing it.

Good luck and hope this helps.